# Python: Why does passing different types of argument into type-defined function not raise any error? Are type annotations only for readability?

Tags: python

In Python, we can define the type of arguments and return data. I just wonder why the code below does not raise any exceptions.

There are two violations here. I am passing float instead of integer and returning a float, while I have already defined "None", which means the function will not return anything.

```
def funct(number: int) -> None:
    number += 1
    return number

print(funct(3.7))
```

Is this feature only to state the argument/return types in terms of readability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python type annotations are not normally checked at runtime (although you [can](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard)). It's possible to write functioning Python code without using the type annotations at all (and that was normal for long time). You're supposed to be using an external static type checker (like [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright)) to get that kind of error *before* you run the program.

It is possible to see the function's annotations at runtime:

```
>>> def funct(number: int) -> None:
...     number += 1
...     return number
...
>>> funct.__annotations__
{'number': <class 'int'>, 'return': None}
```

You can add code to check these things at runtime in various ways, like assert statements.

Good Python IDEs use the type annotations to suggest better completions for you as you write the code. They can also highlight type errors in your editor window.

If you get your types wrong, your program can raise exceptions at runtime, but this isn't guaranteed to happen right away, or at all. In your simple example, you're not using the return value at all, and the only thing you do with the number is add `1` to it, which is a perfectly valid operation for a float in Python, so there's no runtime error.

Comment: I know the assert statement but I thought maybe there would be no need to use assert statements if we define the function as I wrote above. However, I see it is not possible due to your response. Thanks!